# SQL Database not linking to local svn repository in Redgate Source Control

Tags: sql-server, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am trying to link by database to Redgate Source Control but I am getting the error.
I have repository in SVN Source Control system in local folder.

Version of Redgate Source Control: 7.0.6.8775
SVN version: TortoiseSVN 1.11.0

Following is the error message.

Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///D:/SVNRepo/DevDB'

Screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/2pPpZbR1

Anybody know how to fix?

Comment: `file:///D:/SVNRepo/DevDB` isn't a valid URL. The correct address would be something like `http://YourSVNServer/SVNRepo/Project`

Comment: @Larnu My repository is in local folder. How can I use it?

Comment: Connect to your SVN url; like I showed. You can have SVN hosted on your local machine, if wanted, but you still need to use the service and connect to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it, it was version issue.
I created the repository in TortoiseSVN 1.9.4 and it works.

Comment: Great to hear. Your file:// syntax was correct as I've just checked this and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to connect it to a local folder, then you must tell it to connect to `Working folder` from the left pane. You told it to connect to `SVN`, but giving it a path to a folder. Click the radio button next to `Working folder` and browse to the folder where your working copy is stored, or where you want to make one.

[image]